# How to call a trigger from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

This is a WPF Windows app, not a web app.

I am trying to have a 'charms bar' a la Windows 8 fly out from the side of a grid when the cursor lingers near the edge of my control for a certain length of time.

I have it working with ugly buttons and EventTriggers watching for Button.Click, but now I need to get rid of those buttons (training wheels) and call those triggers from codebehind where I am watching for the hover.

How please?

Dave

Comment: Can you please provide a more detailed description of what you want to achieve? A screenshot maybe?